# Why is the execution of my code (the program) happening faster, every time I hit the start button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter

I just recently made a pomodoro clock implementation on python and I was facing some trouble with its execution but I came up with a solution for it but I observed a discrepancy in its execution.

So my whole code and implementation looks something like this (my code is not clean or pretty; sorry about that, I am one of those people who uses a mixture of tabs and spaces):

```
from tkinter import *
from time import *
from threading import Thread


# ---------------------------- CONSTANTS ------------------------------- #

PINK = "#e2979c"
RED = "#e7305b"
GREEN = "#9bdeac"
YELLOW = "#f7f5dd"
FONT_NAME = "Courier"
WORK_MIN = 25
SHORT_BREAK_MIN = 5*60000
LONG_BREAK_MIN = 20*60000


class Reset:
    def __init__(self):
        self.click = False
        self.activation = False

    def button_command(self):
        self.click = True

    def timer_command(self):
        return self.click


# ---------------------------- TIMER RESET ------------------------------- #
timer_reset = Reset()
reset = timer_reset.click

# ---------------------------- TIMER MECHANISM ------------------------------- #

def timer_mechanism():
    minute=0
    if counter[0]<60000:
      if counter[0] % 1000 == 0 and counter[0]/1000<10:
        canvas.itemconfig(clock_counter, text=(f"00:0{int(counter[0]/1000)}"))
        canvas.update_idletasks()
      elif counter[0]% 1000==0 and counter[0]/1000>=10:
          canvas.itemconfig(clock_counter, text=(f"00:{int(counter[0] / 1000)}"))
          canvas.update_idletasks()

    elif counter[0]>=60000:
        if counter[0]%1000==0:
            transition=int(counter[0]/1000)
            while transition>=60:
                minute+=1
                transition-=60


            second=transition
            if second<10 and minute<10:
                canvas.itemconfig(clock_counter,text=(f"0{minute}:0{second}"))
                canvas.update_idletasks()
            elif second>=10 and minute<10:
                canvas.itemconfig(clock_counter,text=(f"0{minute}:{second}"))
                canvas.update_idletasks()
            elif minute>=10 and second<10:
                canvas.itemconfig(clock_counter, text=(f"{minute}:0{second}"))
                canvas.update_idletasks()
            else:
                canvas.itemconfig(clock_counter,text=(f"{minute}:{second}"))
                canvas.update_idletasks()


# -----------------------------New countdown mechanism----------------------------#
i = [4]


def start_countdown():
    if not timer_reset.click and i[0] > 0:

        # keep listening to the function that receives from the button while doing an after for the 25 min and 10 min respectively.3
        timer.config(text="Work", fg=GREEN)
        window.update_idletasks()

        # the solution to this problem is to break up the after process instead of doing it all at the same time make use of small increments so that this after could finish withing a second or two and then go to another function that contains all the timer_reset.click values update and come everytime until we reach a limit somewhere probably an array value that will be updated until we get to the 25 minute mark so this insures as the signal from the button will be accepted.
        execute("Work")

        # start=time()
        # end=time()
        # while end-start<5:
        #     end=time()
        #     timer_reset.click=timer_reset.timer_command()

    else:
        window.destroy()
        timer_reset.click = False
        i[0] = 4
        beginning()


def rest():
    global start_time
    start_time=0
    timer_reset.activation = True
    if not timer_reset.click:

        global restloop
        restloop = True
        global workloop
        workloop = False
        timer.config(text="Break", fg=PINK)

        if i[0] == 4:
            global frame
            frame = Frame(window, width=20, height=20)
            frame.grid(row=3, column=1)

        tick = Label(frame, text="✔", font=(FONT_NAME, 12, "bold"), bg=YELLOW, fg=GREEN)
        tick.pack(side=LEFT)
        window.update_idletasks()


        if i[0] > 0:
            execute("Break")

            if timer_reset.click:

                timer_reset.click = False
                window.destroy()
                beginning()

        else:
            window.destroy()
            beginning()

    else:
        window.destroy()
        i[0] = 4
        timer_reset.click = False
        beginning()
    i[0] -= 1
counter=[0]
def execute(identifier):
    if identifier=="Work":
        window.after(1,mirror,LONG_BREAK_MIN)

    if identifier=="Break":
        window.after(1,mirror,SHORT_BREAK_MIN)

def mirror(value):
    if timer_reset.click:
        window.destroy()
        i[0]=4
        timer_reset.click=False
        counter[0]=0
        beginning()
    elif counter[0]<value:
        counter[0]+=1
        timer_mechanism()

        if value==LONG_BREAK_MIN:
            execute("Work")
        if value==SHORT_BREAK_MIN:
            execute("Break")
    elif value==LONG_BREAK_MIN:

        counter[0]=0
        window.deiconify()
        window.attributes("-topmost",1)
        window.after(300,window.attributes,"-topmost",0)
        window.update()
        rest()
    elif value==SHORT_BREAK_MIN:
        counter[0]=0

        window.deiconify()
        window.attributes("-topmost",1)
        window.after(300,window.attributes,"-topmost",0)
        window.update()
        start_countdown()



# ---------------------------- UI SETUP ------------------------------- #
def beginning():
    global window
    window = Tk(className="Pomodoro")
    window.title("Pomodoro")
    window.config(pady=50, padx=100, bg=YELLOW)
    window.wm_state("normal")

    global timer
    timer = Label(text="Timer", font=(FONT_NAME, 50, "bold"), bg=YELLOW, foreground=GREEN)
    timer.grid(row=0, column=1)
    global canvas
    canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=223, bg=YELLOW, highlightthickness=0)
    tomato = PhotoImage(file="tomato.png")
    canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=tomato)
    global clock_counter
    clock_counter=canvas.create_text(100, 120, text="00:00", fill="white", font=(FONT_NAME, 35, "bold"))
    canvas.grid(row=1, column=1)
    start = Button(text="Start", highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0, command=start_countdown)
    start.grid(row=2, column=0)
    end = Button(text="Reset", highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0, command=timer_reset.button_command)
    end.grid(row=2, column=2)
    window.mainloop()

beginning()
```

And the UI part of my code looks something like this:

[image: This is the GUI of the code, it would be nice if I could have uploaded a video]

**So the discrepnancy I was talking about was that after starting the program and the countdown is happening if by mistake or whatever reason the user presses the *Start* button again the countdown starts to happen faster and if you keep pressing the start button without hitting the reset button it starts counting down even faster and faster.**

Now I think I understand why this might be but this is like a sliver of what the solution might be, I might be completely wrong for all I know but is it because of the after method since every time the user hits the button he is starting another thread of the after method process and this kind of creates a sense/illusion of multiprocessing(parallelism)? I really don't know, to be honest. I might be stretching too far, but please any type of explanation would really be helpful even if it is a jab at my answer. I am very genuinely curious as to why this is happening.

***Any help/suggestion will be really helpful.***

Comment: Without looking at the code too deeply, my guess is that you have a timer leak. That is, each you press the button, a new instance of the timer is started, but the previous one is still running - both generating callbacks to decrement the counter on the screen.

Comment: It also reveals that your on-screen timer is based on reliability of the callback happening at expected intervals. You may be better off keeping track of the actual wall clock time when "start" was pressed and measuring actual seconds elapsed when the callback happens just in case a callback occurs late or early.  It can and will happen.

Comment: It’s exactly as @selbie guessed. Also: time goes faster when you’re older… ;-)

Comment: Yes, I think that is definitely what is happening and you are right! Thank you for your help so much. I should probably close this question now.

Comment: @selbie you are also right about the on-screen timer it is based on the callback happening, but what other alternatives do I have if I separately keep track of the onscreen timer then there will be trade-offs i.e. the timer will not change at the desired time that is showing on the UI

Comment: The general approach to doing any sort of on screen timer or animation is to set the timer interval to 1 second as you'd expect. You could even reduce your interval to something less than a second (e.g. 500-900ms) to reduce the possibility of any clock skew resulting in a skipped beat.   When the timer starts, record the current time value in seconds (ala `time.time()`) to a variable.  When you get your callback, invoke `time.time()` and subtract from the first time call to find out **how much time has actually elapsed**  and use that val to determine what to actually render on the screen.

Comment: @selbie You are right and tbh that was what I was doing at the start but I just didn't know how to set it up. I would call ```time.time()``` in a while loop and let the condition for the while loop depend on it and this way I couldn't let any action from the button control how the program run( I couldn't reset the program and the window would even be unresponsive for a while) but now I think I kind of know what to do. It would be nice if you could tell me how to set it up though i.e., if you have time.